# android- dropbox download files

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am currently working on an android app that is to support the android dropbox api. i am successfully sending the files to my dropbox folder.now i want to download the files and save into the sdcard. at the moment when i am trying to download files it gives me an error this

```
DropboxServerException (nginx): 404 Not Found (File not found)
```

here is my code

```
public void downloadFiles(String filename){
        Log.i("filename is ",filename); 

        File mFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download1");
        try {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            DropboxFileInfo mDropboxFileInfo=mApi.getFile(filename, null, mFileOutputStream, null);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

filename is successfully printing on the LogCat. and the file is in my Photos Folder in dropbox. but i am not able to download it .

Comment: Most probably your file path is incorrect. Everything else in your code seems fine.

Comment: which filepath ? are you talking about this line File mFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download1");
        this path ?

Comment: No.. the filename.. you need to get it like "/Photos/" + filename as you have mentioned it is inside your Photos folder not in your root.

Comment: yeah thank You very much. now i am not getting any file not found errors. but i am not seeing any file in my sdcard. neither i am getting any errors on console. i have to download the files into sdcard. am i doing write ? and i just copied this line File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download1");  i think this line means it creates a folder download1 in sdcard and then store the pic in download folder ?

Comment: Pls post this as your new question thereby others can also see answers..

Comment: Glad I could help! I added is as the answer. Pls accept if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The filename is the problem. You need to get it like `"/Photos/" + filename` as you have mentioned it is inside your Photos folder not in your root.

```
  DropboxFileInfo mDropboxFileInfo=mApi.getFile("/Photos/" + filename, null, mFileOutputStream, null);
```